# element not deleting from list

Tags: python, list

I'm creating a hangman program and I used the `list()` function to turn the word into a list where each letter is its own element. As the user inputs letters as guesses, I want the letter to delete from the list. I've tried the `list.remove(obj)` function and it isn't working as when I type into the shell the name of the list, no letters have been deleted.

```
wordList=list(word)
letter=input("please enter a letter")
if len(letter)>1:
    print('invalid input, you may only enter one letter at a time')
elif letter.isalpha():
    if letter in letters:
        print('you have already entered this letter')
    else:
        letters.append(letter)

        if any(letter in s for s in wordList,):
            print(letter,"is in the word")
            wordList.remove(letter)
```

Edited for length.
Any ideas why the letters aren't being removed from `wordList`?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Your code removes letters from `wordList` when I run your code.

Comment: Note: If a letter is in `wordList` more than one time, then `wordList.remove(letter)` will only remove the first instance. (e.g. If `word = "hello"` then `wordList` will be `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`, and if `letter = 'l'`, then after running `wordlist.remove(letter)`, `wordlist` will be `['h', 'e', 'l', 'o']`, meaning that `'l'` would still be in `wordList`.) You'd probably be better off using a set for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code. suggesting a small change for removing multiple occurrences of the letter.

```
word = "apple"
wordList=list(word)
while wordList != []:
    letter=input("please enter a letter")
    letters = []
    if len(letter)!=1:
        print('invalid input, you may only enter one letter at a time')
    if letter.isalpha():
        if letter in letters:
            print('you have already entered this letter')
        else:
            letters.append(letter)
        if any(letter in s for s in wordList,):
            print(letter,"is in the word")
            wordList =filter(lambda a: a != letter, wordList)
            #wordList.remove(letter)
    print wordList
```

list.remove() - only removes first occurrence of the letter. you could use:

```
filter(lambda a: a!=letter, wordList)
```

Answer (score 0):

i recreated this and it worked for me:
[image]

however i dont think this is the right approach to your problem because .remove() only work with the first match on your list, you could try something like

```
letters = list('_'*len(wordList))
if letter in wordList:
    qtty = wordList.count(letter)
    position = wordList.index(letter)
    letters[position] = letter
if qtty > 1:
    for i in range(qtty-1):
        position = wordList.index(letter, position+1)                
        letters[position] = letter
```

that way you have instead of a full list, removing every time you insert the rigth letter, you will have an empty (actually full of '_' characters) list, adding the letters to its position every time you insert the right letter, that way you can print the current word like this
[image]

i've made a game like this, its on my [github](https://github.com/maybejose/Adivina-la-palabra), the instructions are on spanish but its easy to follow up